# Prove: $ b_n \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} L, \text{as} \ \ b_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\cdot {a_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $(a_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ , a sequence that converges to $L$ ($L$ is not necessarily $\in \mathbb{R}$).

Let $\left(t_{n}\right)$ be a positive sequence such that:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\ \ \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ \ \infty$$

We'll define:

$$ b_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\cdot {a_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}} $$

Prove: $ b_n \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an easy consquence of Theorem of Stolz : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem